# Updating Firestore Document with GoogleSheet AppScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore, google-sheets-formula

I'm finding it hard to update the fields in a firestore collection. The documentIDs of the persons are auto-generated. The inlined code below shows what I've been able to derive and make work, from the tutorials I have followed. Except for the '**updateFirestoreDocument**' function, everything else works without error. How do I rewrite the code to export the modified cells on Google Sheets to the right persons' fields on the firestore collection? Thanks

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(' Firebase')
  .addItem('⏪ Export to Firestore', 'main')
  .addItem('⏩ Import from Firestore', 'menuImport')
  .addToUi();
}

function main() {
  var email = "fireb...ccount.com";
  var key = "-----BEGI...rxEp...RIVATE KEY-----\n";
  var projectId = "co...t";
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  
  var properties = getProperties(sheet);
  
  var records = getRecords(sheet);
  
  var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);
  updateFirestoreDocument(firestore, sheetName, documentId, properties, data);
  exportToFirestore(firestore, sheetName, properties, records);
  
  
}

function updateFirestoreDocument(firestore, collectionName, documentId, properties, data) {
  var documentRef = firestore.getDocument(collectionName, documentId);
  if (documentRef.exists()) {
    properties.forEach(function(prop) {
      documentRef.updateData(prop, data[prop]);
    });
  } else {
    firestore.createDocument(collectionName, documentId, data);
  }
}

function exportToFirestore(firestore, collectionName, properties, records) {
  records.map(function(record) {
    var data = {};
    properties.forEach(function(prop,i) { data[prop] = record[i]; }); 
    if (data[properties[0]] === undefined || data[properties[0]] === null) {
      return;
    }
    // var documentId = data[properties[1]]; // first column
    firestore.createDocument(collectionName, data);
    // firestore.createDocument(collectionName, documentId, data, { id: documentId });
  });
}


function getProperties(sheet){
  return sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
}

function getRecords(sheet) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataToImport = [];
  for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
    dataToImport.push(data[i]);
  }
  return dataToImport;
}
```

- I tried defining documentId
- I was expecting documented to be renamed
- documented fields got modified wrongly

Comment: In your script, it seems that `documentId` and `data` of `updateFirestoreDocument(firestore, sheetName, documentId, properties, data);` is not declared. Is this related to your current issue?

Comment: @Tanaike yes, the error says 'the error says documentId is not defined' and 'data is not defined' when I provide 'var documentId = "xyz";'

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `yes, the error says 'the error says documentId is not defined' and 'data is not defined' when I provide 'var documentId = "xyz";'`, how about `data`?

Comment: The data is the Googlesheet cells/fields. I'm not sure why it gives that error.

Comment: Let's use translation then.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function main() {
  const { email, key, projectId } = getSecrets_();
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);
  exportToFirestore_(firestore, sheet.getName(), getProperties_(sheet), getRecords_(sheet));
}

function getSecrets_() {
  return {
    email: 'fireb..@..ccount.com',
    key: '-----BEGI...rxEp...RIVATE KEY-----\n',
    projectId: 'co...t',
  };
}

function exportToFirestore_(firestore, collectionName, properties, records) {
  records.map(record => {
    const data = {};
    properties.forEach((prop, i) => data[prop] = record[i]);
    return data;
  }).forEach(object => {
    firestore.createDocument(collectionName, object);
  });
}

function getProperties_(sheet) {
  return sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
}

function getRecords_(sheet) {
  return sheet.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
}
```